# sqlcmd on Azure SQL Data Warehouse - SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state after INSERT statement

Tags: sqlcmd, azure-synapse

I am working on a script to reload a table using SQLCMD on Linux connecting to an Azure SQL Data Warehouse database.

After the INSERT statement completes, the next statement fails (but does not end the sqlcmd execution) with the "warning"

```
insert into
  schema.table_temp
(
 ...list of columns
)
select
 ...list of columns
from
   schema.table
;
```

GO (COMMENT--> in script, but not echoed in log.)

```
(0 rows affected)   

IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_nox' )
 DROP TABLE schema.table_nox
;
```

GO (COMMENT--> in script, but not echoed in log.)

```
SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state
```

The script continues to run with each subsequent batch getting the same
SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state "warning"

If I comment out the INSERT statement, the script runs without warning as expected. I speculate the INSERT statement is not closing a cursor and then subsequent commands get the warning which should really be considered an eror and end the execution. (I have the -b flag on in the sqlcmd invocation.)

Is my only solution to break the script into multiple parts?

Comment: I raised an SR on this and was reported to be a known bug.

Comment: can you try doing the same with msqlcli by downloading it from here and see if you are getting the same error:https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/12/12/try-mssql-cli-a-new-interactive-command-line-tool-for-sql-server/

Answer (score 3):

this seems to be an issue with the ODBC Driver that is used by sqlcmd under the hood. Can you confirm if you see this issue with Azure SQL DB? It would also be good to see your odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files. Can you share those out?

In the meanwhile, I would like to recommend a couple of very cool Node.js command line tools that are more suited for Linux and Mac environments:

[SQL-CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-cli)

[Cheetah](https://github.com/wunderlist/cheetah)

Thanks,

Meet

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and adding `GO` between two statements helped me.

Comment: Each of my statements has a GO.  Need to revisit this and see if still present using V13 SQL Server ODBC driver for Linux.  I was using v11.

Comment: Just came across the error again using V13 SQL Server ODBC driver for Linux.  Problem is reproducible.  If an INSERT/SELECT loads zero rows, a subsequent SELECT gets "SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state".

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. When performing `INSERT` via a `SELECT` it resulted in a `(0 rows affected)` response and a `invalid cursor state` error. Adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the start of the script worked for us. As @meet-bhagdev has already pointed out it looks like a driver issue.