# SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to help one of our developers resolve an Azure SQL DB error.  He has attempted to run a script, connecting using sqlcmd and (I presume) ODBC.  It seems no matter what he does he receives the error message "SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state".

His script consists of roughly 80 "insert into table where not exists sub-select" statements.  Some of the sub-selects return zero records.

I read this post which is admittedly almost a year old now.  The short version seems to be "this is a known Azure SQL DB bug".
[sqlcmd on Azure SQL Data Warehouse - SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state after INSERT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403223/sqlcmd-on-azure-sql-data-warehouse-sqlstate-24000-invalid-cursor-state-after)

I know for certain my developer has been able to run these statements previously.  Is that just the nature of a bug - sometimes it occurs and sometimes it doesn't?  Does he need to use a different ODBC driver?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you try doing the same with msqlcli by downloading it from here and see if you are getting the same error:https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/12/12/try-mssql-cli-a-new-interactive-command-line-tool-for-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using ODBC driver 13.1 or later. You can download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).

Comment: Was there a specific issue prior to 13.1?

Comment: I am not sure now but as long as I remember I found some issues related to prior versions on GitHub